# Editing an item with a select that's populated asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a table of items that I need to edit. When edit is clicked, another controller (EditCtrl) edits it. EditCtrl retrieves a list of possible values with an ajax call. The problem I'm having is the dropdown menu doesn't have the item that is selected.

See in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/mUciM4I37aN3lbC6ecIo?p=preview if you click on Porsche, the bottom section says "Car color is red." but the dropdown menu doesn't select red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using `window.setTimeout`, so the options in the select won't even be updated. To get it to work with `window.setTimeout` you need to wrap the content in an `$apply`:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.colors = [
      {code: "#ff0000", name: "red"},
      {code: "#0000ff", name: "blue"},
      {code: "#00ff00", name: "green"}];
  }, 100);
});
```

or you can use the `$timeout` service and skip the `$apply`:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.colors = [
    {code: "#ff0000", name: "red"},
    {code: "#0000ff", name: "blue"},
    {code: "#00ff00", name: "green"}];
}, 100);
```

But as you said that you are using an Ajax call, I doubt this is your real problem (unless you are not using the `$http` service).

After these changes the select in your example still won't select the color correctly. This is because the equality of the color object in `ng-model="car.color"` and the objects in `$scope.colors` are evaluated by reference. So for it to work they need to refer to the same objects.

A working version of your example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nx9nPYMDgPCSVWpOrQoV?p=preview

Comment: Ah, so they're evaulated by reference! I thought I was missing something with how ng-options linked the value in $scope.colors to $scope.car.color.

Your example works although it requires the colors list to be stored in the service. This might get a bit unwieldy if I'm dealing with a lot of lists.

I've updated my example to link $scope.car.color to the item in $scope.colors after $scope.colors is loaded: http://plnkr.co/edit/mUciM4I37aN3lbC6ecIo?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, the link is actually this one! http://plnkr.co/edit/FxXOsurCmewEvRQc6ZRw?p=preview